# Problem adding constraint on the query, data duplication

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

Problem statement:

> Implement a database query that allows users to add or update student result records. The query should check if a record already exists for a given session, course code, and student registration number. If the record exists and is inactive, update the existing record with new values. If the record exists and is active, do not insert a new record. However, if any of the session, course code, or registration number values are different, then a new record should be inserted. The query should use constraints to ensure uniqueness of session, course code, and registration number combinations

this is my  query i wrote

```
    insert:
      ` INSERT INTO Student_Result (` +
      ` SessionYear, CourseStatus, CourseCode, Course, CourseCredit, Class, Teacher,` +
      ` Marks, Grade_LG, GPA, CGPA, SS, StudentRegNo, active ` +
      ` ) VALUES (` +
      ` ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1` +
      ` ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` +
      ` SessionYear = VALUES (SessionYear),` +
      ` CourseStatus = VALUES(CourseStatus),` +
      ` CourseCode = VALUES(CourseCode),` +
      ` Course = VALUES(Course),` +
      ` CourseCredit = VALUES(CourseCredit),` +
      ` Class = VALUES(Class),` +
      ` Teacher = VALUES(Teacher),` +
      ` Marks = VALUES(Marks),` +
      ` Grade_LG = VALUES(Grade_LG),` +
      ` GPA = VALUES(GPA),` +
      ` CGPA = VALUES(CGPA),` +
      ` SS = VALUES(SS),` +
      ` active = true `,
```

and this is my student result table. how can i get uniqueness? that is any of the values between session, courseCode and registration no should be change

```
Student_Result  CREATE TABLE `Student_Result` (
  `ResultID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SessionYear` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `CourseStatus` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CourseCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Course` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CourseCredit` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Teacher` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Marks` int NOT NULL,
  `Grade_LG` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `GPA` float NOT NULL,
  `CGPA` float NOT NULL,
  `SS` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StudentRegNo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ResultID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_studentResult_active` (`SessionYear`,`CourseCode`,`StudentRegNo`,`active`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_SessionCourseRegActive` (`SessionYear`,`CourseCode`,`StudentRegNo`,`active`),
  KEY `StudentRegNo` (`StudentRegNo`),
  CONSTRAINT `Student_Result_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`StudentRegNo`) REFERENCES `Student_Information` (`StudentRegNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

it tried many things but could not get uniqueness

```
 Modify ResultID    SessionYear CourseStatus    CourseCode  Course  CourseCredit    Class   Teacher Marks   Grade_LG    GPA CGPA    SS  StudentRegNo    active
 edit   18  SP23    withdraw    CSE101  applied 4(3,1)  FA19-BCS-G  zaheer ahmad gondhal    0   withdraw    0   3.4 gas FA19-BCS-065    0
 edit   20  SP23    withdraw    CSE101  PF  4(3,1)  FA19-BCS-C  zaheer ahmad gondhal    0   withdraw    0   3.4 gas FA19-BCS-065    1
```